# Azure App Service with Linux Containers: Purge old deployments

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have set up an Azure Linux App Service to deploy a docker image from an Azure Container Registry. Deployment is done via Azure DevOps.

The docker image deployment went fine, but over time, after some redeployments, the log stream indicates that there's no more space on the device and deployments seem to fail. The error occurs after downloading the new container image on app service startup.

The App Service plan quota tells that there is still 250 GB left but I don't know if the container images are stored within the actual web space or whether the download and extraction of container images is done in a separate storage.

My idea was to purge old docker images.
However, when accessing SSH via Kudu, the docker command is not installed and the SSH user does not have root privileges to install docker.

Am I missing something? I didn't find good documentation on this subject.